# KendoTreeView error when dataTextField preoperty contains spaces

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm getting an error with the KendoTreeView drawing due to spaces in our table column naming convention (ex: Name 1). Note "search.columnName" is the table column 'Name 1' which is breaking the treeview due to the space:

```
//treeview source
function populateTreeView(search) {
    debugger;

    var tree = $("#tvwResults").kendoTreeView({
        dataTextField: 'search.columnName',
    }).data("kendoTreeView");
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.2:6080/arcgis/rest/services/WW/WW2/MapServer/exts/RestSOE/Search%20Query?columnName=" + search.columnName + "&operand=" + search.operand + "&searchVal=" + search.searchVal + "&f=", function (data) {
        tree.dataSource.data(data);
    });
};
```

Thanks for the help. This is a show-stopper for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

The `dataTextField` must be a valid JavaScript identifier and should not contain any whitespace.

The simplest solution is to process the server response before you give it to the data source:

```
var tree = $("#tvwResults").kendoTreeView({
    dataTextField: 'name1',
}).data("kendoTreeView"); 

$.getJSON("...", function (data) {
     // map "Name 1" to something which doesn't contain a space e.g. "name1"
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i]["name1"] = data[i]["Name 1"];
     }
     tree.dataSource.data(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the sql view for the time being, as this is a deadline for today. Only problem I have is defining the child. I do so using the dataTextField I thought: dataTextField: ["Name1", "Cars"], but it doesn't show up. I see the node showing Name1 (2 of them in my example I'm running) but nothing for Cars.